# How to assign a separate colour for each task on checked list box

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

my task is to create a planner . so i have a checked list box whenever i enter a message with a number it displays the message with the colour assigned to the number . but when i add another message with another number and colour it changes the whole checked list box and message to that colour number i just entered.

so i want to add multiple messages into my checked list box without it changing  to the last number colour i just entered .

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;

    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "5")
    {
        checkedListBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + "\t" + dateTimePicker1.Text);

    }
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "4")
    {
        checkedListBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + "\t" + dateTimePicker1.Text);

    }

    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "3")
    {
        checkedListBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + "\t" + dateTimePicker1.Text);

    }
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "2")
    {
        checkedListBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold;
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + "\t" + dateTimePicker1.Text);

    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that with any built-in properties. You either need to implement your own or use a different control. Check the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588322/how-to-dynamically-change-set-checkedlistbox-item-fore-colour

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListView for this. First add a ListView to the form and then go to properties of the listview and change CheckBoxes Property as true. Then try below code. You can change the colors as you want.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Text = textBox1.Text + "\t" + dateTimePicker1.Text;
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {                              
            item.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            item.ForeColor = Color.Blue;                
        }
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
```