# How to add checkbox to legend do enable\disable series in VB.net MS chart

Tags: vb.net

How to add checkbox to legend items do enable\disable series by checking check box in VB.net MS chart

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the built-in WinForms chart control, then it doesn't have this feature but you can use a "support" control for the legend.
I would suggest hiding the default legend and adding a CheckedListBox to the form with the names of the series as items (all checked by default) and keep track of the indexes that are unchecked/re-checked. The order of the items indexes must correspond to the series order.
In order to hide the legend, you can set the Enabled property to false. In the designer properties go to Legends->...->select the default (usually unique) element and set Enabled = False. In this case "Enabled" means "Visible". 
Or you could just do

```
 Chart1.Legends.Item(0).Enabled = False
```

at runtime.

To hide a series that is unchecked you can use:

```
Chart1.Series.Item(i).Enabled = False
```

and to show it again

```
Chart1.Series.Item(i).Enabled = True
```

where i is the series index and the CheckedListBox item index.
At this point you'd probably want to implement the colors feature that the default legend has and this can be a little tricky. 
It may be necessary to use an extended CheckedListBox since the built-in one doesn't have a forecolor/backcolor for each element. See this about drawing your own CheckedListBox.[Dynamically change CheckedListBox item ForeColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588322/how-to-dynamically-change-set-checkedlistbox-item-fore-colour)

Alternatively you could use a checkbox for each series, since CheckBox has ForeColor and BackColor properties, or a checkbox with an image that represents the series color. In both cases, if there is a good number of series or series can by changed at runtime, you'd probably want to use a Panel or FlowLayoutPanel for the checkboxes that you generate at runtime. It is not convenient adding all the checkboxes at design time. You could for example make a loop for all the series in the chart in the form load event, where you generate the legend checkboxes and an image for the series color by using

```
Dim b As Bitmap = New Bitmap(16, 16)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b)
        g.Clear(Chart1.Series.Item(i).Color)
    End Using
```

Comment: Can you please provide me complete code to enable and disable series by checking checkboxs

Comment: I am not getting how to add checkbox control to legends, please help me by providing code

Answer (score 0):

On Vertical Track Bar after sliding getting error like minimum value of the axis is greater than the largest data point value for MS multi series chart in VB.NET.

My code is 
  Private Sub YAxisTrackBar_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles YAxisTrackBar.ValueChanged
        DashForecastNRPChart.ChartAreas("Test Chart").Axis.Maximum = YAxisTrackBar.Value
    End Sub